# Any efficient approach to find the minimal vectors?

Tags: algorithms, vectors, order-theory

$\bullet$ A vector $X=(x_1,\cdots, x_m)$ is less then vector $Y=(y_1,\cdots,y_m)$ when $x_i\leq y_i$, for each $i=1,\cdots, m$, and for at least one $j$, we have $x_j<y_j$.

$\bullet$ A vector $X\in \Pi$ is a minimal vector when there is no any vector, say $Y\in \Pi$, such that $Y<X$.

To be more clear, consider the following example.

**Example 1.** Assuming $\Pi=\{$(3, 4, 6, 1), (2, 3, 5, 2), (3, 3, 7, 1), (3, 4, 5, 3)$\}$, we have

$\Pi_{min}=\{$(3, 4, 6, 1), (2, 3, 5, 2), (3, 3, 7, 1)$\}$.

Now, assume that a set of *m*-tuple vectors, say $\Pi$, is given, and we need to find the set of all the minimal vectors in $\Pi$, i.e., $\Pi_{min}$. A vivid approach is to compare all the vectors in $\Pi$ and remove the non-minimal ones. Assuming *k* as the number of vectors in $\Pi$, since each vector is *m*-tuple, the time complexity of comparative technique is $O(mk^2)$.

I would like to know if there is a more efficient method for this problem. Actually, I need an approach with time complexity less than $O(mk^2)$.

I highly appreciate your taking time to read my question and to give your answers.

Comment: Some efficiency can be gained by eliminating vectors which are found not to be minimal during the process of comparisons.  However if all $k$ vectors are incomparable, then all are minimal and $O(k^2)$ pairwise comparisons are needed to verify this.

Comment: O(k^2) are necessary for a general poset, but why would that many comparisons be necessary for vectors in R^m?  @hardmath

Comment: @zyx : If $m$ is small the number of incomparable vectors (length of antichain) can be bounded, but I missed it if there is a restriction on $m $.

Comment: Even if all the vectors are an antichain,  why is an O(k^2) all-pairs comparison necessary?  There could potentially be something better that uses the embedding in R^m, it is not a random poset. @hardmath

Comment: I did not understand your mean by incomparable vectors. For sure, to see that if two vectors do not eliminate each other in comparative method, we need to compare all the components of two vector. As you see in the given example, both vectors (3, 4, 6, 1) and (2, 3, 5, 2) are minimal ones while by the first three components it seems that the first one is not minimal. So, we need *m* comparisons for two vectors and in the worst case, k(k-1)/2 vector comparing, and as a result the time complexity would be $O(mk^2)$.

Comment: For sure, during the comparison process, it is probable that several vectors are removed via comparing to a vector, and so the actual number of comparisons could be really less than $O(mk^2)$. However, as you may agree, to compute the time complexity of a technique, we need to consider the worst case. The number of comparisons in an artificial example could be $m(k-1)(k-2)/2$. For example, in the above-mentioned example, if we consider a set with the first three vectors, we will need 12 ( exactly $m(k-1)(k-2)/2=4(3)(2)/2$) comparisons to find the minimal ones.